# Mongoose add asynchronous virtual field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Recipe` model and a `Like` model. I want to set a virtual field on the `Recipe` model to get the number of likes on a recipe when I fetch it from the database. But it returns an empty object.

```
RecipeSchema.virtual('likeCount').get(async function () {
  const likes = await Like.find({ recipe: this._id });

  return likes.length;
});
```

Comment: I think you may need to attach `.exec()` to the end of `Like.find(...)` - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec

Comment: Just tried it. It's not working, I got the same result.

Comment: What does the definition of `Like` look like? Also have you tried using the `countDocuments()` function instead? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.countDocuments

Comment: @KevinHoopes I just tried using the `countDocuments()`. It returns the count after the request. The issue is, async functions don't work in the virtuals.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but if virtuals can't handle `async` functions, you can always keep references to an array of Like objects in your `RecipeSchema`.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const recipeSchema = Schema({
  ...
  likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Like' }]
  ...
});
```

Then you'll have an array in the document that you can refer to the length of for a count of likes, and you can [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) them later if you need the actual information inside the Like documents.

Note: You would have to write logic to append new Likes to the `likes` array in the proper Recipe.